# binding to datepicker in datagrid rowdetails

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid. When a row is click on the rowdetails is shown. In the rowdetails I have another datagrid next to the datagrid is a DatePicker.

So the main datagrid has a collection of a custom object. When a row is clicked the sub datagrid is bound to the selecteditem.Funds (another list) (code shown below). The selectedItem also has a datetime property which I want to bind to my DatePicker however I cannot get it to work.

I am using the line below,

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedItem.DateEffective2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I assumed (maybe wrongly that because the datepicker is in the rowdetails I would be able to bind to the selectedItem, guess I'm wrong?

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding HldLogEQCurr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedHldLogEq, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                          Style="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate1}"
                          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeaderCenter1}"                                            
                          RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row1}"
                          CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell1}"                                    
                          RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeader1}"                              
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                           
                          Background="Silver" 
                          Margin="50,50,50,50"                              
                          CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          RowHeaderWidth="30">

                        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid x:Name="RowDetailGrid"            
                                      Margin="5"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                            Height="250"
                                            CornerRadius="5">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"/>
                                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="400"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               Margin="5,5,5,5"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               FontSize="12"
                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                               Foreground="Black" 
                                               Text="Select action to take">
                                            </TextBlock>
                                            <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Funds,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"                                                                  
                                                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DG_Row}"  
                                                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_ColumnHeader}" 
                                                  RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DG_RowHeaderNested}"
                                                  CellStyle="{StaticResource DG_Cell}" 
                                                  Background="Silver"
                                                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                                                  VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                                                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                                                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                                  Margin="50,5,5,20"
                                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fund Code" Binding="{Binding Code}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="75"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fund Code SS" Binding="{Binding CodeSS}" IsReadOnly="True" MinWidth="75"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Number of Rights" Binding="{Binding CurrentNominal, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rights To Exercise" Binding="{Binding NewNominal, StringFormat={}{0:N0}}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Take Cash" Binding="{Binding OptionOne, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                                                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Take Stock" Binding="{Binding OptionTwo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                                                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Take Both" Binding="{Binding OptionThree, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                            </DataGrid>

                                            <Grid Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="180"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" 
                                                               Text="Select Date Effective From"/>
                                                    <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                                                BorderThickness="0" SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedItem.DateEffective, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="200"/>
                                                </StackPanel>


                                            </Grid>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Entered" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding DateEntered, StringFormat={}\{0:dd-MMM-yy\}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="75"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Effective" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding DateEffective, StringFormat={}\{0:dd-MMM-yy\}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="75"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sedol" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Security.Sedol}" MinWidth="75"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Security.Name}" MinWidth="200"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ratio" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding RatioNew}" MinWidth="75"/>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: The DataContext for the DatePicker should already be the SelectedItem, try changing it to:
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateEffective2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: thanks, now works!. If you put your comment as answer happy to mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataContext for the DatePicker should already be the SelectedItem, try changing it to:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateEffective2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Also, your sub-DataGrid's ItemsSource could be simplified from:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Funds,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
```

To:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Funds}"
```